# export { default } from 'react-native-web/dist/vendor/react-native/NativeEventEmitter/RCTDeviceEventEmitter';

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, metro-bundler

Im doing a React Native project, and whenever i run 'npm start' and choose 'w' for web in the Metro Bundler, i'll get this error:

```
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
```

Above this error, it tells me this:

```
    C:/Users/silas/node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native-web/dist/exports/DeviceEventEmitter' in 'C:\Users\silas\node_modules\expo-modules-core\build'
C:/Users/silas/node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/EventEmitter.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native-web/dist/exports/NativeEventEmitter' in 'C:\Users\silas\node_modules\expo-modules-core\build'
C:/Users/silas/node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/Platform.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native-web/dist/exports/Platform' in 'C:\Users\silas\node_modules\expo-modules-core\build'
C:/Users/silas/node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/EventEmitter.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native-web/dist/exports/Platform' in 'C:\Users\silas\node_modules\expo-modules-core\build'
../../../../../../node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/SyntheticPlatformEmitter.web.js:5
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-web/dist/vendor/react-native/NativeEventEmitter/RCTDeviceEventEmitter'
  3 |  * registered in the API layer with `NativeEventEmitter`.
  4 |  */
> 5 | export { default } from 'react-native-web/dist/vendor/react-native/NativeEventEmitter/RCTDeviceEventEmitter';
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this error? I've tried to run 'npm install'.